# Javers - How to use custom tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javers

According to the Javers's document: (ref: https://javers.org/documentation/repository-configuration/)

> JaVers creates four tables in SQL database:
>
> **jv_global_id** - domain object identifiers, 
>   **jv_commit** - JaVers commits metadata,
>   **jv_commit_property** - commit properties, 
>   **jv_snapshot** - domain object snapshots.

My currently using **Spring Boot + Javers** 
**My question:** Do we have any way to config/custom the tables's name or the column's name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't change table names nor col names, but you can specify a schema name.

Comment: Oh okie, got it ! Thanks for your information. I've decided to use only javers-core instead of javers for Spring Boot due to lack of customization for my project's needed.

Comment: @Bartek - Is there any way if we can give you another name to these 4 tables as per my industry standards ?

Comment: javers is OSS project, feel free to contribute a PR